# is there some ability to get jenkins-cli working with external auth provider?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

all@

i'd like to use jenkins-cli, but seems it can work with local users only. is there some ability to use external auth provider, like LDAP or OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins to choose from:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Authenticationandusermanagement

The [Standard Security Setup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup) guide has instructions on active directory and a link to the [LDAP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin) plugin.